# Possible theorem determining sum of residue of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

As in the title, I'm currently learning complex analysis, and wondering if there's any particular theorem determines whether the sum of residues of a given function is real/complex directly from the function itself, without any other computations (residue theorem is good, but not direct enough).

For instance, is there a theorem claiming that given some fine properties (eg. boundes on function, holomorphic, maps unit circle to unit circle, etc.) on a complex-valued function $f(x)$, we can know the sum of residues of $f(x)$ must be real/complex?

Comment: Do you know the “residue theorem”? The sum of residues inside a closed contour can be computed as an integral.

Comment: @MartinR I do, but that doesn't give us a direct enough way of checking properties of the residues; anyway thanks for your answer, and I'll edit the question to be more precise.

Comment: Well, at least if your function $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a given region, you automatically know that the sum of residues is zero there :)

Comment: @jasnee uh that's true...My bad; I've edited my question to make it exclude this case (that can be shown by a well-known theorem).

Comment: I don't see the purpose of your question. For example, the second paragraph considers wether the sum of residues is real or not. This would mean that the integral is pure imaginary, but what is the interest of such an information ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a general theorem on the sum of the residues:

For a complex function $f$ defined and holomorphic on the whole plane except possibly at a finite number of points, the [sum of the residues is 0](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Residue_of_an_analytic_function), though you have to include the residue at infinity (in the link the statement of the result is just below the definition of the residue at infinity).

If you don't want to think about points at infinity, you can impose the additional condition that $f$ decay faster than $1/z$ (in other words $zf(z)\to 0$ for $|z|\to \infty$), in which case the residue at infinity is 0, so for such an $f$ the sum of the residues at all complex points is 0.